# What are the CSS selectors for alternating rows and specific columns in GnuCash?

Tags: windows-10, gtk, gnucash

GnuCash lets you modify styles in the app by editing ***gtk-3.0.css*** in *%APPDATA%\GnuCash*.

With this method, I've been able to tweak most things I want. I'm also able to identify css selectors for *some* items via the [Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector). However, I haven't been able to figure out how to style alternating rows or individual columns on the Accounts page as shown in this screenshot:

[image: GnuCash Accounts page]

For alternating rows, I've tried the following, and neither seems to work:

```
treeview tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #888;
}

#gnc-id-account-tree tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #888;
}
```

I've also tried `td:nth-child(1)` for the first column, and that didn't work either.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK%2B/Inspector

Comment: Have you tried appending `!important` to the end of the class command like this: `background-color: #888 !important;`

Comment: @Giacomo1968 That's a good idea. But unfortunately it seems GTK doesn't even support `!important`. (Adding `!important` to an existing CSS property seems to break it.)

Comment: Well, can you look in the inspector and find what chain of CSS commands lead to that color? In my experience with real world CSS, so times you have to really explicitly set the whole CSS chain with each item and — sometimes — even explicitly like: `.parent > .child > .grandchild > .final_element`

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I wish viewing an element in the app was as easy as viewing an element on a webpage. The Inspector doesn't appear to show css information for anything more granular than the entire table (I assume it's a table), unless I'm missing something.

The most specific path I can figure out from the Inspector is `treeview#gnc-id-account-tree:backdrop`, which is basically the entire tree.